# NSmutablestring with 2 line breaks crash the program

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to create an Nsmutableattributed String that starts with line break, the code are like below:

```
let dateString = TimeUtils.formatTimeOnly(from: data.date!)
let dateMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "\n\(dateString)")
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: (dateString.count + 2))
dateMutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 11)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray], range: range)
```

if I only start the string with only one \n it will crashed the program on the addattributes line, but if I use \n\n then it wont break the program. Can I know what's really going on here?

Comment: Please add the crash message to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one extra character then `dateString.count + 2` is longer than the string and you get a crash because the range isn't valid.

Why base the range length on `dateString.count + 2`? Why not build the string you want, then pass that string to the `NSMutableAttributedString` initializer? Then you can directly get that string's length. And why not pass the desired attributes to the initializer since you want them applied to the whole string anyway?

Besides that, you can't use `count` on a Swift string to get the length when working with `NSString` or `NSAttributedString`. You need to use `dateString.utf16.count`. This is because `NSRange` for `NSString` and `NSAttributedString` is based on 16-bit characters.

Here is a simpler way to create the attributed string where the attributes are applied to the whole string:

```
let dateString = TimeUtils.formatTimeOnly(from: data.date!)
let dateAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 11)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray]
let dateMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\(dateString)", attributes: dateAttributes)
```

Comment: wow thanks for the answer, but now got a weird situation appeared, the date I got is formatted like "Sep 11, 3.00pM", the last M character is not taking effect on the addattreibutes. the utf16.count also return a correct length

Comment: @kiki: check ur `DateFormatter` format with "MMM d, h:mm a"